# Javascript/jQuery - Make array based on variable index of <option>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to get the number of `options` in a `select` tag and then generate the same number of image paths from that.

```
$optionIndex = $("option", "select").index; // 2
imagePath = "/images/slider/slide-"
$images = "[" + imagePath + $optionIndex + ".jpg" + "]"; 

$(window).load(function() {
  var $slider = $(".slider").slider({
    images: $images // ideally this would show ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg" etc…]
  });
}
```

Comment: You're creating a string, not an array. Use a `for` loop or `$.map()`.

Comment: @PSL I went with your solution, however I'm curious how Satpal's solution stacks up in performance. Side note, some of my other related scripts seem to have stopped working now. So I'm at a crossroads currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop through and create an array like

```
$images = [];
for (var i=1;i<= $optionIndex ;i++)
{ 
   $images.push(imagePath + i + ".jpg");
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BD6mb/)

Answer (score 1):

One thing is `$("option", "select").index` should be `$("option", "select").index()`. Otherwise you will end up getting the function reference of `index` method. But i guess you wanted to take the length and then iterate.

But here you can just do:

```
 var $imagePathArray = $("select").find("option").map(function(i){ //<-- zero based index
        return  imagePath + i + ".jpg" ;
 }).get();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FXgrg/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
var selOps = $('#selectId>option'), imagePath = '/images/slider/slide-', imgs = [];
selOps.each(function(i){
  imgs[i] = imagePath+this.val()+'.jpg';
});
$(window).load(function(){
  var $slider = $(".slider").slider({
  // not sure there is an images property of the slider object, so I'm confused about this part
  });
});
```